# Fragment with recycler view inside NestedScrollView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

I have a NestedScrollView with 2 fragments inside. One of them ( *comment_container* ) has a recyclerView inside, and this recyclerView has *wrap_content* height. Because of that the RecyclerView doesn't recycle items, all views are loaded at the beginning - because of that when there is a large amount of data the performance is so bad. I dont know how to archive what I what.

When i set the fixed size (ex. 500dp) the performance is pretty good. But then scrolling issues appeared, because NestedScrollView and RecyclerView have separate scrollers. But when I set "nestedScrollingEnabled" on recyclerView there is no way to see all of the views because height is fixed.

Do you know how to fix this?

**activity.xml**

```
     <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:id="@+id/scroll_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:overScrollMode="always"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/scroll_container"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/backgroundGrey"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true">

                    <FrameLayout
                        android:id="@+id/detail_container"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@android:color/white"/>

                    <FrameLayout
                        android:id="@+id/comment_container"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

**fragment.xml:**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 (...)
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/comments_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

(...)
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Have you found any good solution to this?